# robot_localization global ekf node(GPS) and local ekf node(odom) cause shifting of base link tf frame?

Tags: ros2, rviz, mobile-robot, gps, nav2

I have a problem with my robot with GPS.
I have a Scout robot with F9P gps device getting gps and having dual ekf node which have the following config file. But once I launch these nodes and visualize in Rviz2, the base_link related to map or odom keep shifting([video of shifting in rviz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m_kwdc6B9fdHNyuT6MBtb1m1VRy9ZSa-/view?usp=drive_link))  in rviz2.
Is this will happen when the GPS not having a good accuracies? Or I have the other problem? Thank you.

This is the my ekf and navsat yaml file.

```
ekf_node_odom:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: true
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true
    smooth_lagged_data: true
    # publish_tf: true


    map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
    base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
    world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

    # X, Y, Z
    # roll, pitch, yaw
    # X', Y', Z'
    # roll', pitch', yaw'
    # X", Y", Z"

    odom0: /odom
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true, true, true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]


    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_relative: false


    imu0: /imu/data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true, true, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true, true, true,
                  true, true, true]
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false


    process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 1e-3, 1e-3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.01, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]

    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1.0, 1.0, 1e-9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

ekf_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: true
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: map



    # X, Y, Z
    # roll, pitch, yaw
    # X', Y', Z'
    # roll', pitch', yaw'
    # X", Y", Z"

    # Wheel Odometry
    odom0: /odom
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true, true, true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false


    # GPS odometry
    odom1: /gps/odom
    # odom1: /gps/odom
    odom1_config: [true, true, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 10
    odom1_nodelay: true
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1.0, 1.0, 1e-3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.01, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]

    initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0, 1.0, 1e-9, 1.0, 1.0, 1e-9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

navsat_transform_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    frequency: 10.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: -0.14 # For lat/long of Atlanta, Georgia
    yaw_offset: 0.0  # if IMU reads 0 when facing magnetic north instead of east then set parameter to pi/2
    zero_altitude: true
    broadcast_cartesian_transform: true
    broadcast_cartesian_transform_as_parent_frame: true
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: true
    wait_for_datum: false
```